# How do I communicate with an HTTPLISTENER that I have created?

Tags: vb.net, httplistener

I've got this code below that creates an HTTPLISTENER that is nicely waiting at listener.GetContext().

How do I communicate with this from another VB app?  I cannot seem to get WebRequest.Create to work with the URI that my HTTPLISTENER example is using.  This line of code from a second app is not working:

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(prefixes(0))
```

Here is the code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim prefixes() As String = {"http://*:8080/HttpListener/"}

    ProcessRequests(prefixes)

End Sub

Private Sub ProcessRequests(ByVal prefixes() As String)
    If Not System.Net.HttpListener.IsSupported Then
        Console.WriteLine( _
            "Windows XP SP2, Server 2003, or higher is required to " & _
            "use the HttpListener class.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' URI prefixes are required,
    If prefixes Is Nothing OrElse prefixes.Length = 0 Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("prefixes")
    End If

    ' Create a listener and add the prefixes.
    Dim listener As System.Net.HttpListener = _
        New System.Net.HttpListener()
    For Each s As String In prefixes
        listener.Prefixes.Add(s)
    Next

    Try
        ' Start the listener to begin listening for requests.
        listener.Start()
        Console.WriteLine("Listening...")

        ' Set the number of requests this application will handle.
        Dim numRequestsToBeHandled As Integer = 10

        For i As Integer = 0 To numRequestsToBeHandled
            Dim response As HttpListenerResponse = Nothing
            Try
                ' Note: GetContext blocks while waiting for a request. 
                Dim context As HttpListenerContext = listener.GetContext()

                ' Create the response.
                response = context.Response
                Dim responseString As String = _
                    "<HTML><BODY>The time is currently " & _
                    DateTime.Now.ToString( _
                    DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo) & _
                    "</BODY></HTML>"
                Dim buffer() As Byte = _
                    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString)
                response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length
                Dim output As System.IO.Stream = response.OutputStream
                output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

            Catch ex As HttpListenerException
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            Finally
                If response IsNot Nothing Then
                    response.Close()
                End If
            End Try
        Next
    Catch ex As HttpListenerException
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Finally
        ' Stop listening for requests.
        listener.Close()
        Console.WriteLine("Done Listening...")
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use Prefixes as it is! You may need to replace "*" with "127.0.0.1" to be able to connect to your listener. So if your prefix is something like:

"http://*:8080/HttpListener/"

Then you need to call following URL to be able to connect to your HTTP Listener:

"http://127.0.0.1:8080/HttpListener/"
--or --
"http://localhost:8080/HttpListener/"

I hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to verify that you HttpListener is in fact listening is to navigate to the url you are listening for with a browser. If it cannot find it you will get a 404 error.

Once you have verified that the listener is working, then try using the WebClient to communicate with it in your code. WebClient has a much simpler interface than HttpWebRequest and takes care of reading and writing from the streams for you.

```
string result = WebClient.DownloadString("http://google.com");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```